# access function and change veriable from URL

Tags: php, function, url, methods

I want to access this function and change the variable from the URL how can i Do that . i try this to echo something and its work 
http://test.local/UUser.php

```
<?php echo '<p>'. 'Hello Husam' . '</p>'; ?>
```

but how i can access this function inside UUser.php .
For example i need to change $order = "ASC" to $order = "DESC".

```
public function getBooks($start = 0, $limit = 2, $order = "ASC")
 {

   $sql_start = $start * $limit;
   $sql_limit = $limit;
   $sql_order_by = $order;

   $query = "SELECT Library.nameOfBook, userBook.book_id, userBook.user_id FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username=:username ORDER BY Library.nameOfBook $sql_order_by LIMIT $sql_start, $sql_limit";
   $statment = $this->db->prepare($query);
   $statment->execute([
       ':username' => $this->username
   ]);
   $result = $statment->fetchAll();

  echo "<table id='myTable' border='1'>

  <tr>
   <th><a id='sorter' href='#'>Books</a></th>
   <th>Action</th>
   </tr>";
   foreach($result as $row){
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['nameOfBook'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" ."<input type='submit' id='delete".$row['book_id']."-".$row['user_id']."' onclick='deleteBook(this)' name='delete' value='Delete'>" . "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
   }

   echo "</table>";
   echo "";
   return count($result);
   echo '<p>'. 'Hello Husam' . '</p>';
 }
```

Comment: How do you call getBooks function ?

Comment: i try this if(isset($_GET['getBooks'])){
   getBooks();
}

Comment: he give me this error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getBooks() in /var/www/html/UUser.php:

Comment: It means that you didn't include `getBooks` function properly

Comment: so how i do that ?

Comment: It depends on your codes on `UUser.php`